# eBay API Quantity not returning the real value

Tags: php, ebay-api

I have noticed a very strange thing in eBay in the last few days. I am using both GetItem and GetSingleItem calls to get the quantity of an item. Since Monday (I think), the quantity the calls are returning is not correct. For example, if I open the ItemID [231802662855](http://www.ebay.de/itm/231802662855) in eBay, I see the item being available, I am able to purchase it, and the available quantity is 1. But if I make the API calls to get the quantity, both GetItem and GetSingleItem return Quantity = 0.

Here are the request and response for GetItem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <RequesterCredentials>
        <eBayAuthToken>...</eBayAuthToken>
    </RequesterCredentials>
    <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
    <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
    <ItemID>231802662855</ItemID>
    <OutputSelector>Item.Quantity</OutputSelector>
</GetItemRequest>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetItemResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Timestamp>2017-07-07T07:23:52.205Z</Timestamp>
    <Ack>Success</Ack>
    <Version>1009</Version>
    <Build>E1009_INTL_API_18420867_R1</Build>
    <Item>
        <Quantity>0</Quantity>
    </Item>
</GetItemResponse>
```

And here are the request and response for GetSingleItem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetSingleItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <ItemID>231802662855</ItemID>
    <IncludeSelector>Details</IncludeSelector>
</GetSingleItemRequest>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetSingleItemResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Timestamp>2017-07-07T07:30:36.420Z</Timestamp>
    <Ack>Success</Ack>
    <Build>E1021_CORE_APILW_18481359_R1</Build>
    <Version>1021</Version>
    <Item>
        ...
        <Quantity>0</Quantity>
        ...
    </Item>
</GetSingleItemResponse>
```

And if you open the same item in eBay, you can see it's actually available and it has 1 quantity. [Link](http://www.ebay.de/itm/231802662855)

Does anyone else have this problem? Did you find a solution for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug from eBay. They have now fixed the Shopping API and they said they will fix the Trading API soon too.